# How to customize print layouts in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, printing, windows-photo-gallery

I need to (add/modify) my customized layouts to the `print Pictures` layouts listed in Photo Gallery in Windows 7.

I was wondering if there is a simple way to do that within Photo Gallery only?

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Suggest you use other software. One of the replies to a similar [Microsoft Community question](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/forum/gallery-wlsettings/how-do-i-print-custom-size-photos-in-windows-8/6f84bdb5-e0d5-426b-973e-0add9b5e2d49?db=5&auth=1) lists a number of them.

Answer (score 1):

This won't be the answer you're looking for, but - no, not really. Windows is pretty limited as to what you can do with the basic photo software. However, there are free-ware/trial-ware photo programs and web-based programs that will allow you to do just about anything you'd like. But since photo/video editing is a million-dollar industry, I don't think you'll find anything 100% free that will do everything exactly as you want. 
If you're willing to look outside Microsoft software, Gimpshop is a (free) alternative to PhotoShop, or PhotoELF has a 30-day trial with full functionality. Best of luck to you!